# Determining the probability of a certain pareto function

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $X_1,\ldots, X_n$ be a sequence of i.i.d observations from: $f(x; \alpha) = \alpha x^{-\alpha - 1},$ $x \geq 1$ in which $\alpha$ is an unknown parameter.

For $y>0,$ calculate $G(y) = P(\ln X \leq y)$. Derive the pdf for $Y = \ln X$ by differentiating $G.$

So, I'm not quite sure where to begin for this question. I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $x\geqslant 1$ we have
\begin{align}
\mathbb P(X\leqslant x) &= \int_1^x f(s;\alpha)\ \mathsf ds\\
&= \int_1^x \alpha s^{-\alpha-1}\ \mathsf ds\\
&= 1 - x^{-\alpha}.
\end{align}
Hence for $y>0$ we have
\begin{align}
\mathbb P(Y\leqslant y) &= \mathbb P(\log X\leqslant y)\\
&= \mathbb P(X\leqslant e^y)\\
&= 1-(e^y)^{-\alpha}\\
&= 1-e^{-\alpha y}.
\end{align}
Differentiating yields
$$
f_Y(y) = \alpha e^{-\alpha y},
$$
in other words, $Y$ has exponential distribution with parameter $\alpha$.